# In Unity, how can I make a mesh a "portal" or cut-out that reveals an underlying image

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity, I want to create an effect where an arbitrary shape (a quad or a cube) acts as a "portal" that reveals an image. No matter which way the object rotates, or what the camera perspective is, the image "inside the portal" always faces the same direction.

[image: See-through plane shows a pattern]

In this image, I have a 3D plane that reveals a checkerboard pattern texture, like a cut-out in the scene. Whichever way the plane object is rotated or camera is positioned, the image inside the portal remains completely fixed. The inner image doesn't move or distort.

I want to be able to do this with multiple objects in the scene. So a sphere could be a portal to a fixed picture of a dog, or a cube could be a portal into a tiled pattern. Even knowing the name of this effect would be helpful. Do I have to write a shader to do this?

Comment: You will need to write a shader, but it's fairly trivial.  What it sounds like you're asking for is a 'background' image that is fixed relative to the screen rather than the 'world'.  The term you're looking for is "Screen Space Texture" (or UV).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a Screen Space shader. Where most shaders will calculate uv coordinates based on a pixel's location on the mesh, these shaders use the location on the screen. Here's a [great article](https://www.ronja-tutorials.com/2019/01/20/screenspace-texture.html) about them.

Hot tip: this is commonly used with a second camera rendering to a RenderTexture in order to create portals to 3D spaces.

You may need to play with the tiling to get the aspect ration of your texture correct, this shader assumes it is the same as your screen, i.e. 16:9

```
Shader "Ahoy/Screen Space Texture"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "Queue"="Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent"}

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM

            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 screenPos:TEXCOORD1;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                o.screenPos = ComputeScreenPos(o.vertex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                float2 uvScreen = i.screenPos.xy / i.screenPos.w;
                uvScreen = TRANSFORM_TEX(uvScreen,_MainTex);
                return tex2D(_MainTex, uvScreen);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```